# php json_encode & decode

Tags: php, json

I have a json array storred in a file looking like:

```
["bla bla","bla bla2","bla bla3"]
```

And if I want to remove one of these objects from the json array with the code below the json converts to another type of array looking like:

```
{"1":"bla bla","2":"bla bla2","3":"bla bla3"}
```

I dont want this to happen because it screws up code in another place. How can I achieve this?

```
$eng = json_decode($en_banners, false);

unset($eng[$id]);

$myFile = "languages/banners.php";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "<?php \$de_banners='".json_encode($eng)
```

Comment: Based on your usage, you might have better luck with `var_export`.

Comment: Try `json_decode($blah, true)` - parse JSON as assoc array and not object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript arrays are zero-based so there's no possible way to create a JavaScript array from a PHP array with gaps unless you fill the gaps:

```
$en_banners = '["bla bla","bla bla2","bla bla3"]';
$eng = json_decode($en_banners, false);
var_dump($eng);
$id = 0;
$eng[$id] = null; // Rather than: unset($eng[$id]);
var_dump(json_encode($eng));
```

If array keys are not relevant, you can simply ignore them:

```
$en_banners = '["bla bla","bla bla2","bla bla3"]';
$eng = json_decode($en_banners, false);
var_dump($eng);
$id = 0;
unset($eng[$id]);
var_dump(json_encode(array_values($eng)));
```

If none of these solutions apply, we need more data :)

Comment: The first one makes the array post stay but with a null value. 
But the second one works very well! Thanks! :)

Comment: That's because you cannot have gaps! Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Set at your json_decode false to true.. 
If its false the decoder makes php Object, if its true it makes PHP Array from that json..

```
$eng = json_decode($en_banners, TRUE);
```

After that json_encode convert php Object to json Object, php Array to json Array..

P.S

after unset add...

```
    $eng = array_values($eng);
```

To cleanup array keys

```
$eng = json_decode($en_banners, TRUE);

unset($eng[$id]);
$eng = array_values($eng);
$myFile = "languages/banners.php";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "<?php \$de_banners='".json_encode($eng);
```

Comment: Nope, the problem is still there! :(

Comment: Looks like this should work.  There might be some magic happening if you are accessing `$eng['some_string']` to turn it into an object.

Comment: @bdares at the example its $eng[$id] so I don't think for strings :)

Comment: This doesn't work because there's no consecutive index anymore.

Comment: @DanLee I tested it and it works as it wanted.. and did you test it?

Comment: With `array_values`, it works of course. It was based on your non edited answer with just forcing it to an assoc array, that didn't work for me.

Comment: I put false because I dont want an associative array. You can see that true makes it an associative array in the php documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php